# Lost docker-machine directory, is there any way to recover it?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have docker containers successfully deployed and running in an EC2 instance that was created and provisioned with `docker-machine`.

However, I have lost the docker-machine directory under `~/.docker/machine/machines` since my backups failed recently. Is there any way to recover and recreate the docker-machine ? I have access to the EC2 account but I can't seem to log-in to the EC2 instance as it required ssh certificates.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: The directory consists of `config.json` and a bunch of TLS certificates and keys. Restoring config seem to me a possible task, as for certificates I think the only way is finding and replace them.

Comment: Fair enough, I think it might be possible to recreate the directory if one can access the EC2 instance, is that possible though without having the certificates ?

Comment: Without ssh key to the instance you will not be able to replace certificates on it. Thus you can't restore the machine. However, there is a way to create a new EC2 instance using an ssh key pair you do have. It won't be the same _instance_ but who cares as long as the data is there. After that you can proceed with replacing certificates.

Comment: I've explained how can one restore access to an instance in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721493

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that helped.

In the end I followed this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-ec2reset.html, ssh'ed into the EC2 instance with the new recovery keys, copied the server certificates from `/etc/docker` into a new directory under `~/.docker/machine/machines`, updated the `config.json` file, copied the new ssh key as `id_rsa` in the same directory and voila.